# Why don't we put parentheses in the function of setInterval in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, time, setinterval

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>INTERVAL</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="func()">CLICK IT</button><br><br>
    Time: <br>
    <p id="para">here</p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var inter = setInterval(func,2000);
        function func()
        {
            var d = new Date();
            var t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
            document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = t;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here, in the line [**var inter = setInterval(func,2000);**] , why dont we use **func()** instead of **func** ?

Comment: with the parenthesis, you are invoking the function right away but this not what you want, you want to invoke it after a certain elapsed time.  In the `setInterval(...)` example, you are simply passing the function as a parameter (by its name) and when the interval hits the interrupt (i.e. the time has elapsed) the function is invoked...

Comment: See more explanations here: https://cmorinan.medium.com/passing-functions-as-arguments-in-javascript-tips-and-pitfalls-d29bbd4522a9

Answer (score 3):

You don't put parentheses after func in setInterval because `setInterval(func(), 2000)` would try to call the return value of `func` as a function instead of calling `func` itself.

Answer (score 1):

Using parentheses with functions means I want to call the function and if it returns a result, I want it.

```
int func() { return 1337; }
let x = 10 + func();
```

What about if I want to pass the function as argument so that I want to call it in my internal side? I don’t want its result or internal process at its calling time but later.

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` expects the reference to a function, which will be called once the time you passed is elapsed.

in your example `func` is a function reference and `func()` is how you call the function, and in your case, `setInterval` will take care of the calling part.

Comment: Javascript doesn't have pointers. You're going to confuse people coming from languages that do have pointer.

Comment: Thanks, @PoorlyWrittenCode I have updated the answer now...

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the difference between a [function call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and a [function declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function).

A function declaration is the body of a function itself.

A function call says do the thing described in the function declaration.

`func` = function declaration

`func()` = call function func

`()` means `do this now` in javascript. If you put it after a function declaration, it means do the proceeding function declaration now. But you can also use it to perform inline operations. `let a = (1 + 2)  * 3;`

`setInterval` is looking for a function declaration, which it will call. So passing it a function call would be redundant, and thus fail.

Comment: Passing a function as parameter is not the same as declaring a function; this answer is not helpful as it introduces more confusion.  Question was about A or B and you are comparing B and C

Comment: You're passing a `function declaration` as an `argument`. But hey, we're all here to learn. [JavaScript Function Parameters](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp)

Comment: I'm not sure if you are agreeing with me or not :) - the link you shared does not support your answer.  - perhaps we splitting hairs on semantics here. Good day